# GCC optimization steps

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization

I am working or performance evaluation and I encountered a problem: when I add some instruction to the code it executes faster than the initial code, I think due to compilers optimization (without specifying any).

How do compiler optimization works? In particular are they performed while converting C to Assembly or in the step from Assembly to binary code?
I suppose both, however is possible to know which optimizations are performed in each step?

I have looked at assembly but I have found only slightly differences so I suppose that some architecture specific optimization is involved.

Thank you!

Comment: [Here is a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) by a compiler writer who encounters an issue like this and explains it. The answer is _"compilers are complicated beasts"_.

Comment: there is a flag named "OPTIM_DISABLE" you have to set it to yes to disable the optimization. If you prevent any variable optimization then use volatile

Comment: @SohilOmer Where do you see that flag? To explicitly disable optimizations pass `-O0` when invoking `gcc`, but it is the default already. `volatile` is going to prevent some optimizations but far from all.

Comment: Thank you for the video! I'm using gcc without option (equivalent to -O0, I suppose). Does gcc perform some optimization anyway? I have found some default optimization in the gcc manual but not related to my problem, however I am still reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly is binary code, to all intents and purposes BTW. Most optimisation occurs when the higher level language is compiled to assembly. It's weird that you add functionality and it gets faster... but compiler optimisation is kinda dark magic.

You may be able to get to the bottom of it, you could compile your C to assembly (gcc -S) and see what it did for your versions... Of course bear in mind not all instructions are created equally, this will help you more if you have some awareness of assembly and how CPUs and buses and memory, etc, work at a low level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have yet analysed the assembly, roughly calculating costs using a table specific for my cpu.
My concern is about the usage of hidden general purpose register, those improvement are performed directly by the cpu and not while converting from assembly to binary?
I suppose that pipelining is directly handled by the cpu, right?

Comment: Not entirely, the CPU is responsible for the pipeline of course as instructions are executed, but compilers know about pipelining and may take steps to produce assembly that takes fullest advantage of it, such as reordering instructions.

Comment: So, when I get the assembly using gcc -S, it is still optimized to take advantage of pipelining and the following transformation in binary code is barely a 1:1 translation ams_op -> bin_op?

Comment: Yes, output of gcc -S will include optimisation, so gcc -S -g, gcc -S -O0 and gcc -S -O1 will be more and more optimised. Assembly and binary code really are the same, the only possible exception being if a particular operation the CPU can execute is not representable by an assembly mnemonic and its parameters, and I'm not honestly sure if that happens still these days or not. For sure that would be a very rare case though.